# Shopware 6 Global Custom Field returning null for secondary language contexts

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I have created a custom field set via plugin class.

```
    $customFields = [
        [
            'name' => self::CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME,
            'active' => true,
            'global' => true,
            'config' => [
                'label' => [
                    'en-GB' => 'Password Protected Page',
                    'de-DE' => 'Passwortgeschützte Seite'
                ],
                'translated' => false
            ],
            'customFields' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'password_site_password',
                    'type' => \Shopware\Core\System\CustomField\CustomFieldTypes::TEXT,
                    'config' => [
                        'label' => [
                            'en-GB' => 'Password',
                            'de-DE' => 'Passwort',
                        ],
                        'translated' => false
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'relations' => [
                [
                    'entityName' => 'category'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];

    $customFieldSetRepository = $this->getCustomFieldRepository();

    if (!$this->customFieldsExist($customFieldSetRepository, $installContext->getContext())) {
        foreach ($customFields as $customFieldSet) {
            $customFieldSetRepository->upsert([$customFieldSet], $installContext->getContext());
        }
    }
```

This works as intended for the main language. Concerning secondary languages the custom field returns null. **The value can also be defined in different languages**, which is **not** intended.

The custom field is supposed to be defined in one language only. The value should be the same in any context. How do I achieve this?

Comment: How do you fetch the value? How does it look in the database?

Comment: Did you find the solution?